# Django select users groups

Tags: python-3.x, django

How do I use Django's User and Group models to allow the user to select and switch one of their assigned groups

forms.py

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=models.UserGroup
        fields = [‘group’]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs)
        super (UserGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].queryset = Group.objects.filter (user=user)
    def clean_role(self):
        role = self.cleaned_data.get('group’)
        if role is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Choose role")
return role
```

views.py

```
def select_role(request):
    if request.method == ‘POST’:
    form = UserGroupForm(request.user, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid:
        user_group = for.save(commit=False)
        user_group.user = request.user
        user_group.save()
        return redirect(‘home’)
    else:
        form = UserGroupForm(request.user)
    return render(redirect, ‘select_role.html’, {‘form’:form})
```

Answer (score 0):

> myuser.groups.set([group_list]) 
> myuser.groups.add(group, group, ...)
> myuser.groups.remove(group, group, ...) 
> myuser.groups.clear()
> [[Source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

As you can see, setting or adding groups is fairly straight forward.

```py
def select_role(request):
    if request.method == ‘POST’:
        form = UserGroupForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            user = request.user
            groups = Group.objects.filter(form.cleaned_data['groups_list'])
            user.groups.add(groups)  # or maybe user.groups.add(*groups)
            user.save()  # don't exaclty know if this is necessary
            return redirect(‘home’)
    else:
        form = UserGroupForm(request.user)
    return render(redirect, ‘select_role.html’, {‘form’:form})
```

This is following another approach than one would initially take. You save the group to the user, **not** the user to the group.

Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: It doesn’t work, i think i need update_or_create method

Comment: Of course the Group has to exist before you can assign it to a user. You could instead of `Group.objects.filter` use `Group.objects.get_or_create`, add that group to your database and then assign it to the user.